# Как сделать, чтобы блок заполнял всю высоту родителя?

Tags: html, css

```
Есть такой html:
    <div class="contacts__content cf">
            <div class="info f_left">
            </div>
            <div class="location  cf f_right">
                <div class="map f_left">
                    <section id="google-map">
                        <div id="google-container"></div>
                        <div id="zoom-in"></div>
                        <div id="zoom-out"></div>
                        <address>улица Артема, 80, Киев, город Киев, Украина</address>
                    </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Нужно, чтобы класс `.info` был в высоту как `.contacts__content`. Если я сейчас ставлю `height:100%`, то блок схлопывается и без `padding` не показывается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример с использованием `flex`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.col-1 {
  flex: 1;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.col-2 {
  flex: 2;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    2
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
  </div>
</div>
```

`<br />` Добавлено, чтобы визуально раздвинуть правый блок, и вместе с ним пространство блока `container` займет левый блок, и наоборот.

Comment: Спасибо. Пока что не помогло, но это что то интересное. По-гуглю)

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов как это не помогло? Пример рабочий, значит вы что то не правильно делаете

Comment: А, я паддинг не убрал)Теперь круто) А это не костыль?

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов нет, не костыль. `flex` кроссбраузерная технология. Почитайте о ней, она решает огромное количество проблем, которые как раз решались костылями.

Answer (score 0):

```
.info {
    position: absolute; 
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: Либо использовать `flex`. Пора бы уже :)

Comment: не сработает если у родителя `position:static` или не установлен

Comment: Нет, абсолют туда не вставить. Или обертку делать...